# How to handle force closed in IOS Apps Swift

Tags: ios, swift

ASK : Is it possible to handle our app before getting force closed; like make a dialog and show the error and then force close or something like that ?

Comment: when app is force close at means that something happens that is not league or possible to Handel so at this point no have any chance to display dialog.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common case, no way.

Try to use  `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` in UIViewController. This is the closest. Or detect using a remote server.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/responding_to_memory_warnings